# undefined variable within a setInterval callback

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I am implementing a simple countDown function that, given a num in seconds, counts down num, num-1, ..., 0 and `console.log`s *"Ring Ring Ring!!!"*.

When `num` is `0` using JavaScript built in `setInterval` method. The problem with my implementation is that the variable `num` is printing as an `undefined` variable.

I've looked at this for an hour now and can't sort it out. Can someone help out? Thanks!

```
function countDown(num) {
    var timer = num * 1000;
    var intervalId = setInterval(function(num) {
        if (timer !== 0) {
            console.log("Timer: ", num);
            num--;
            timer -= 1000;
        } else if (timer == 0) {
            console.log("Ring Ring Ring!!!");
            clearInterval(intervalId);
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You've `num` in setInterval function just remove that

```js
function countDown(num) {
var timer = num*1000;
var intervalId = setInterval(function(){
    if(timer !== 0){
        console.log("Timer: ", num);
        num--;
        timer -= 1000;
    } else if(timer == 0){
        console.log("Ring Ring Ring!!!");
        clearInterval(intervalId);
    }
}, 1000);
}

countDown(20);
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the param `num` from here:

```
setInterval(function(num));
                     ^
```

That param is hiding the outer param from `function countDown(num) {...}`

```js
function countDown(num) {
  var timer = num * 1000;
  var intervalId = setInterval(function() {
    if (timer !== 0) {
      console.log("Timer: ", num);
      num--;
      timer -= 1000;
    } else if (timer == 0) {
      console.log("Ring Ring Ring!!!");
      clearInterval(intervalId);
    }
  }, 1000);
}

countDown(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for you to pass `num` as an argument to the anonymous function

So the below code should work : -

```js
function countDown(num) {
    var timer = num*1000;
    var intervalId = setInterval(function(){  //removed num argument
        if(timer !== 0){
            console.log("Timer: ", num);
            num--;
            timer -= 1000;
        } else if(timer == 0){
            console.log("Ring Ring Ring!!!");
            clearInterval(intervalId);
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```